# Docker Desktop 3.1.0 for Windows 10 Installation Failed

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10

I have Windows 10 Pro version 1903 (build 18362.836). Hyper-V is enabled. Docker Desktop 3.1.0 failed to install with the following error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Component CommunityInstaller.EnableFeaturesAction failed: 
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
```

Comment: try updating your computer using Windows Update (in the setting app)

Comment: As stated in the comment on Jan 8th in github you can use chocolatey to install it through powershell. 
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9758

Comment: Try the solution at the end of [this post](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9780).

Answer (score 0):

To anyone getting this error:

```
Component CommunityInstaller.EnableFeaturesAction failed
```

The fix for me was enabling this service:

```
Windows Modules Installer
```

Note I used [Wu10Man](https://github.com/WereDev/Wu10Man) to do this, but I think you can also just use the normal Services App.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling `Windows Modules Installer` didn't work for me. What did work was installing through [winget](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/) like so:

`winget install Docker.DockerDesktop`

The current Docker version as of writing this is `3.3.3`.